# CodeBlocks SFML audio library will not work

Tags: c++, audio, codeblocks, sfml

I've been following some youtube tutorials for SFML in codeblocks, and we just reached audio. Up until this point, I've only used the graphics aspect but had no issues. Though for audio, I've tried switching from using .ogg to .wav files and back in my code and played around with everything for a while but the program just won't work. I don't really understand how the libraries work (I'm new if that isn't apparent) but I have looked through the lib file of sfml and have every file there in my linker settings, so I don't understand why I continue to get errors. Anyways I am given a ton of errors and would like to simply use the audio part of SFML. Here's all the data you need to crack the case:

Actual Code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    sf::Vector2i screenDimensions(800,600);

    sf::RenderWindow Window;
    Window.create(sf::VideoMode(screenDimensions.x, screenDimensions.y), "A Window");

    sf::Clock clock;

    sf::SoundBuffer soundBuffer;
    sf::Sound sound;

    if(!soundBuffer.loadFromFile("punch.ogg")){
        std::cout << "Can't find audio file" << std::endl;
    }

    sound.setBuffer(soundBuffer);

    float moveSpeed = 10000.0f;

    while(Window.isOpen()){

        clock.restart();
        sf::Event Event;
        while(Window.pollEvent(Event)){

            switch(Event.type){
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                Window.close();
                break;
            case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                if(Event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape){
                    Window.close();
                }
                if(Event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::P){
                    sound.play();
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        Window.display();
        Window.clear();
        }
}
```

Linker Settings: (I've tried moving the order around a ton yet it doesn't help)

```
sfml-audio-s-d
sfml-network-s-d
sfml-graphics-s-d
sfml-window-s-d
sfml-system-s-d
flac
ogg
vorbis
vorbisenc
vorbisfile
openal32
jpeg
freetype
ws2_32
gdi32
opengl32
winmm
```

And lastly, all of the errors:

```
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_write'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_write'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_write'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_write'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_write'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| more undefined references to `oggpack_write' follow|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_readinit'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_read'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_read'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_readinit'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_read'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_read'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_read'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_read'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_read'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| more undefined references to `oggpack_read' follow|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_bytes'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_read'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_bytes'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_read'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_read'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_read'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_read'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_read'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| more undefined references to `oggpack_read' follow|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_writeinit'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_bytes'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_bytes'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_bytes'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_writeclear'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_writeclear'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_writeinit'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_write'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_write'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_write'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_write'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_write'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| more undefined references to `oggpack_write' follow|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_bytes'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_bytes'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_bytes'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_reset'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_writeclear'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_bytes'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_bytes'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_bytes'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_reset'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_write'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_write'|
E:\CODING STUFF FOR C++\zzz.External Libraries\SFML-2.3\lib\libvorbis.a(info.o):info.c|| undefined reference to `oggpack_write'|
||More errors follow but not being shown.|
||Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...|
||=== Build finished: 50 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 2 seconds) ===|
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The audio library is not being linked to. That's what an undefined reference error means. So you should probably check if your project file is linking to the static lib file(`.a`) exist in your path.

<strike>Another thing is that you don't need any of the libraries you currently have in your linker settings EXCEPT for the SFML libs, because they are already linked into the SFML static lib file.</strike> Not true in 2.3, but true in 2.1

Comment: That's absolutely not true. When statically linking SFML you **have to** link SFML dependencies.

Comment: @Alayric read the manual. You only have to link to the .a files. At least with the -s.a files. With audio you need to make sure that the executable is started in the same directory that the dlls are for sndfile and openal

Comment: In red in the [official tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/start-cb.php): "when static linking, you will have to link all of SFML's dependencies to your project as well"

Comment: @Alyric I remember not having to link SFML's deps on 2.1. So I might be wrong if it's 2.3, because I have not used that.

Comment: @Alayric That is not the case with the last version of SFML that I used which was 2.1, so I am wrong.

Comment: Yes indeed, that change dates back from 2.2! Since this question is about 2.3 I think it would be wise to remove the wrong part of your answer so that it doesn't mislead people.

Comment: ok, so again, i'm pretty new to all of this; can i get some definitions to project file, static lib file, and path? I get what you're saying but I don't really know how to do as you say. Lastly, I tried removing all of the libraries in my linker settings except for the SFML ones but it caused a ton of errors when I tried running some test code that previously has and still does work with all of the libraries above linked

Comment: also, @alayric are there any other libraries that I need to link that I dont? Or do I just need to do what hschmale said (except for the part about getting rid of the extra libraries)

Comment: No, it looks like you have linked everything.
@HSchmale thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The correct linking order is:

```
openal32
flac
vorbisenc
vorbisfile
vorbis
ogg
```

not:

```
flac
ogg
vorbis
vorbisenc
vorbisfile
openal32
```

or else it gives you undefined references to 'oggpack_***'

Answer (score 0):

Please use the correct linking order:

```
openal32
flac
vorbisenc
vorbisfile
vorbis
ogg
```

Not:

```
flac
ogg
vorbis
vorbisenc
vorbisfile
openal32
```

Or else it will give you undefined references to 'oggpack_***'

Comment: Hey, are you the same guy as that @user13163901 above? :)